PLS-00382: el tipo de la expresión no es correcto al recibir un BLOB en un json
tengo un Store Procedure que recibe datos de un API usando la variable de entrada IJson, la cual lleva los siguientes datos:
"NAME": "test",
"DESCRIPTION": "test test",
"IMAGE": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA3YAAANK.... texto largo

Al recibir ese Json en mi SP hago lo siguiente:
vIMAGE BLOB;
IF iJson IS NOT NULL THEN 
        vNAME:= JSON_VALUE(iJSON,'$.NAME');
        vIMAGE:= JSON_VALUE(iJSON,'$.IMAGE');   <-- ERROR AQUI
        vDESCRIPTION:= JSON_VALUE(iJSON,'$.DESCRIPTION');

Pero al compilar mi SP me parca un error al recibir el valor de vIMAGE:
PLS-00382: el tipo de la expresión no es correcto
Saben como puedo escribir la expresion para que me reciba el BLOB ?

primero debes eliminar ´data:image/png;base64,;´ y luego hacer un decode puedes hacer un: REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(iJSON, '$.IMAGE'), '^data:image/[a-z]+;base64,', ''); para eliminarlo y luego un UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE
